# Dual Shield Build

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, feats, fighter, shield

Really badly want to do either a Dwarven dual shield paladin or fighter.

I would basically want to be a wall that can push, taunt and just be an undying shield carrier all around. Is there ANY form of build that I can do to make this work efficiently while being at the front line protecting everyone? If so please do mention it.

EDIT: I would very much like to run dual shields in 5e. Dual wield seem to be one of the ways to currently do this. I do know that AC bonus will not stack. Is it possible to do dual shields to be effective or useful?

As well as this, my main focus is to be the defense line for everyone on my team and to protect them to as much of a degree as possible. I wish to be, quite literally, my teams shield. My goal is pretty simple in theory but I cannot seem to build it. I am somewhere along the lines of heavy armor and two shields, giving me higher AC, and with a high constitution. I hope I have separated the questions a little easier to be understood, and I apologize for having multiple questions in one question.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel like there are two close-but-not-identical questions in here. (1) "can I dual shield and get something out of it?" (2) "How can I best be a wall?" And there seems to be an underlying assumption that dual-shielding will make a good wall. Can you help disentangle the two? Perhaps even pose as separate questions?

Comment: Also, 5e experts may not be conversant with 3.5 Shield Warriors. Could you include a summary of the desirable elements?

Comment: Since you're trying to generate ideas for a possible character build this question is [better suited to a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: Alright thank you both. What forums would you recommend???

Comment: [A list of forums we recommend](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970). On the other hand, I think there is a stack-question in there. I just thing we need to massage it into shape.

Comment: I don't understand: if you know that the second shield doesn't improve AC, what do you imagine doing with it?